# How to query one JIRA issue with gerrit query API

Tags: api, rest, curl, gerrit

I would like to query one issue say JIRA-123, below command is what exactly I want:

```
https://gerrit.mydomain.com/q/JIRA-123
```

I try to do it with below command but it search string JIRA-123 instead:

```
ssh -p 29418 user1@gerrit.mydomain.com gerrit query --format JSON --current-patch-set JIRA-123
```

What's the equivalent gerrit query api command for "https://gerrit.mydomain.com/q/JIRA-123"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET  https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=JIRA-123
```

OR

```
auth=$(echo -n USER:PASS | base64)
curl --header "Authorization: Basic $auth" --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=JIRA-123
```